Can someone please explain the difference between a parking pass, a parking permit, a ticket you get from a parking machine and a receipt?
I have heard that parking permits are valid for several days, several weeks, several months or even a year and that a parking pass is only for a couple of hours or for one day. Is this information correct?
Question 1: Is the information I have been told correct?:I have heard that parking permits are valid for several days, several weeks, several months or even a year and that a parking pass is only for a couple of hours or for one day. Is this information correct?
Question 2: If so, how does a parking pass differ from a receipt or a ticket you get from a parking machine when parking in a parking spot next to a road or when parking in a parking garage. I mean, all three are just for a couple of hours or for one day. I really don't get it.
Question 3: When parking in a parking spot next to a road or in the parking lot or parking garage of a supermarket, what do you call the slip of paper you need to buy to park there for a couple of hours or even for the entire day?
Thank you in advance

This terminology can vary by locality (sometimes one parking spot to the next).

Can you please explain the differences in your region?

Q3. The piece of paper you get from a machine (which you display inside the car) is called a ticket. But a parking ticket can also be a penalty notice affixed to the car.

Can I ask whether you're from the UK or from the US or from somewhere else? Thank you, by the way.

In UK, a parking permit is generally long-term permission to use a car park. A parking pass is probably a short-term permission to park, say for a visitor attending a meeting. But the validity is what is says on the ticket, pass or permit. Q3 again: a long term parking permit can also be called a 'season ticket'. There's no clear-cut terminology.

It's rather messy. I recently bought a parking pass for the Atlanta Aquarium online. When I got to downtown Atlanta, I followed signs for "vehicles with permits". I got lost, and presented the parking receipt sent to my email on my phone, and was directed to the gate with the ticket machines.

So you had to buy a ticket? I still don't understand the difference.

The difference is what it says on the ticket (or the conditions of sale), not in a dictionary. There are no strict definitions about parking. What one organisation calls a permit might be called a pass by another.

So all these terms are interchangeable?

Q1. Yes. Q2, street or shop parking is by ticket obtained from a machine. Q3. The ticket is a receipt. It shows that you have paid. Other systems are all electronic, paid by phone, with no ticket, and policed automatically by number plate recognition cameras.

Is this a question about meaning? It depends on which state, country or region you are speaking of. A parking ticket in the UK is a fine when you park somewhere illegally. There is a fixed sum which you are expected to pay within a certain date. A parking ticket is also released by a machine in a car park, which gives the owner permission to leave their vehicle for a number of hours or even days-think of airport parking or parking lots  at airports for example.

A dictionary will tell you exactly what a receipt is. Perhaps you thought your question would be better or more impressive if you asked about more words, even if "receipt" is clearly different in meaning. But it's better to ask a smaller question such as the difference between two words.

This is for parking in the US, northeast. But it probably applies to most places in the US and many other places as well!
Your first question: I have heard that parking permits are valid for several days, several weeks, several months or even a year and that a parking pass is only for a couple of hours or for one day. Is this information correct?
Answer:

In general, that is 100% accurate. Residents or local businesses in an area of a city/town can often get a parking permit for parking in their area. It is generally supplied by a local authority. Those who are not residents or local businesses, cannot get them. Permits of any kind are generally for some amount of time and you often pay for them. Those permits are for street parking or parking in private or public lots (car parks).

A parking pass is issued to a person (vehicle) for a limited amount of time, usually, on a particular day, sometimes longer for a particular parking lot/area. So, let's say you visit a large factory/business but do not work there, the owners of that business can give you a parking pass for the day/days of your visit. Parking passes are usually free. Or let's say, you go to a lawyer's office where there is reserved parking for everyone in that building, the lawyer can give you a pass for the time you are there. In general, passes of any kind are temporary.


In my town south of Boston, visitors can get a parking pass from residents who have parking permits. Those passes are good for a week (at a time), for example. Pass is again, like permit, a general term that allows a person to "pass", be allowed to be in a place for a certain amount of time as defined by the pass issuer.
Question 1: Is the information I have been told correct?:I have heard that parking permits are valid for several days, several weeks, several months or even a year and that a parking pass is only for a couple of hours or for one day. Is this information correct?
Answer: Yes, in general,that is true. Just like a construction or building permit. Permits have time limits and require renewal depending on the limit.
Question 2: If so, how does a parking pass differ from a receipt or a ticket you get from a parking machine when parking in a parking spot next to a road or when parking in a parking garage. I mean, all three are just for a couple of hours or for one day. I really don't get it.
Answer: When you park by buying a ticket from a machine, either on the street (in the US) or inside a garage, a parking ticket comes out of the machine. (CAVEAT: parking ticket is also the term used to impose a penalty on a driver for parking in an illegal parking spot.) A ticket is issued to you and you need it to exit the garage by feeding it into a machine which then spits it back out with validation or spits out another piece of paper which acts as a receipt,  a receipt as you would receive for any kind of purchase. So, the ticket can be the receipt (proof of purchase) or it is validated with the machine stamping a time code on it. After validation, it becomes a receipt.
On the street for metered parking, you usually have to purchase parking by an amount of time: one hour or three hours, for example. There are often time limits on the  time you are allowed to park and then you have to buy more time. Parking meters (on the street) may or may not issue receipts. There are no receipts for paying with quarters for an hour or so for street parking.
There is also monthly parking in parking lots (usually not open air lots), in which case, a receipt will be issued in various ways such as email. A receipt is just proof of purchase.
Now, with the advent of digital everything, many of these street machines, called parking meters, in outside parking lots or on the street are all digital. You pay with a credit card or an app. You take the receipt and put it on your dashboard. If you have paid with quarters for two-hours, for example, no paper receipts are issued.
Question 3: When parking in a parking spot next to a road or in the parking lot or parking garage of a supermarket, what do you call the slip of paper you need to buy to park there for a couple of hours or even for the entire day?
Typically, there is no charge for supermarket parking in the US. Supermarkets and other stores in malls all have parking lots and parking is always free. Unless you are in New York City (for example), in which case, you probably have walked to the supermarket and not parked at all as people don't drive to supermarkets there. in general. (OK, so  I lived in NYC and sometimes did drive way uptown to a supermarket but even there the parking was free.) If we were charged for parking at supermarkets, that would truly be the last straw. :)
[I am posting this for informational purposes only, and do not intend this to cover every single parking situation in all US states.]

In comments Weather Vane wrote:

Q3. The piece of paper you get from a machine (which you display inside the car) is called a ticket. But a parking ticket can also be a penalty notice affixed to the car.

And wrote:

In UK, a parking permit is generally long-term permission to use a car park. A parking pass is probably a short-term permission to park, say for a visitor attending a meeting. But the validity is what is says on the ticket, pass or permit. Q3 again: a long term parking permit can also be called a 'season ticket'. There's no clear-cut terminology.

And wrote:

The difference is what it says on the ticket (or the conditions of sale), not in a dictionary. There are no strict definitions about parking. What one organisation calls a permit might be called a pass by another.

And wrote:

Q1. Yes. Q2, street or shop parking is by ticket obtained from a machine. Q3. The ticket is a receipt. It shows that you have paid. Other systems are all electronic, paid by phone, with no ticket, and policed automatically by number plate recognition cameras.


In a comment Mari-Lou wrote:

Is this a question about meaning? It depends on which state, country or region you are speaking of. A parking ticket in the UK is a fine when you park somewhere illegally. There is a fixed sum which you are expected to pay within a certain date. A parking ticket is also released by a machine in a car park, which gives the owner permission to leave their vehicle for a number of hours or even days-think of airport parking or parking lots  at airports for example.


Both those things are the same in the States and are in my answer.
